# To extract field from JSON file comparing it with plain text file matching values and extract specific field from JSON file

Tags: json, awk, sed, file-comparison

I have `file1.json` and plain text `file2`, Where using `file2` values compare with `file.json` with matching values of `file2` there will be the corresponding field which is CaseID in `file1.json` the resultant file should consist of those values. I have mentioned cases below with expected results.

I was trying to extract using the awk tool, where I don't get my expected answer

```
 awk -F, 'FNR==NR {f2[$1];next} !($0 in f2)' file2 file1
```

**file1.json**

```
{
    "Cases": [{
            "CaseID": "100",
            "CaseUpdatedByUser": "XYZ",
            "Case": {
                "CaseName": "Apple",
                "ID": "1"
            }
        },
        {
            "CaseID": "350",
            "CaseUpdatedByUser": "ABC",
            "Case": {
                "CaseName": "Mango",
                "ID": "1"
            }
        },
        {
            "CaseID": "440",
            "CaseUpdatedByUser": "PQR",
            "Case": {
                "CaseName": "Strawberry",
                "ID": "1"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**file2**

```
Apple
Strawberry
Mango
```

**Expected output:**

```
100
350
440
```

Comment: This might help: `jq -r '.Cases[] | "\(.Case.CaseName);\(.CaseID)"' file1`

Comment: @Cyrus My system is configured with customized repo, so will not be able to download ```jq```

Comment: @Cyrus is this command comparing values with file2. i dont see anything about file2 in command

Comment: No. Correct. But this makes it easier to process the output with `awk`.

Comment: @Cyrus somehow i managed to pull out result using ```jq``` .. with this result i used ```awk```  but it will result out file contents of last argument which is passed.. 

```jq -r '.Cases[] | "\(.Case.CaseName);\(.CaseID)"' file1 >> f1```  I re-directed result into f1
contents of f1 file
~~~
Apple;100
Mango;350
Strawberry;440
~~~
 now if use awk ``` awk -F, 'FNR==NR {f2[$1];next} !($0 in f2)' file2 f1``` it will result into contents of f1

Comment: Is the order of the numbers important?

Comment: @Cyrus yes it should be sorted and should be in ascending order

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With `jq`, `awk` and `sort`:

```
jq -r '.Cases[] | "\(.Case.CaseName);\(.CaseID)"' file1 \
  | awk -F ';' 'NR==FNR{array[$1]=$2; next} {print array[$1]}' - file2 \
  | sort -n
```

Output:

```
100
350
440
```

Answer (score 2):

How about if you write an `extract.py` module that helps you to get the exact information that you need.

The module is flexible so it can be imported as a module into any project.

I've tried with a complex and long json file and it worked just fine.

The code of this module is:

```
#extract.py

def json_extract(obj, key):
    arr = []

    def extract(obj, arr, key):
        if isinstance(obj, dict):
            for k, v in obj.items():
                if isinstance(v, (dict, list)):
                    extract(v, arr, key)
                elif k == key:
                    arr.append(v)
        elif isinstance(obj, list):
            for item in obj:
                extract(item, arr, key)
        return arr
    
    values = extract(obj, arr, key)
    return values
```

For further explanation, this is the [URL](https://hackersandslackers.com/extract-data-from-complex-json-python/) of the original post ( [Extract Nested Data From Complex JSON](https://hackersandslackers.com/extract-data-from-complex-json-python/) ).